# How do I render a totally black silhouette?

Tags: rendering, light

Hi I need to render a mesh totally black - the single object does not have to interact with the lighting. How to do that?

Comment: sorry u do not get the point - if I do use a complete blak shader it can still interact with the lighting. I need the mesh not to interact with the lighting.

Comment: No t sure to understand, but a black shader with all the values to 0.0 and ray visibility not to cast shadows could be the option, but try to explain a bit more. What render engine are you using, what kind of scene are you using, and so.

Comment: use an Emission node with a black color?

Comment: Hello :). You can simply unplug everything from the surface input. Then it'll be totally black.

Comment: Hi many thanks for your answer.

In the meanwhile I have experimented a quick solution. I have assigned to the mesh a material then I have deleted the principled bsd leaving the output node alone and that made the mesh totally black with no reflections. To get rid of the shadows I have disabled them in object properties.